# ElesticSearch REST HTTP request through redirected URL

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, redirect

I am asking community help because I have some trouble requesting an ElasticSearch database with a special redirected URL.

Can you please give an hand on this ?

Thank you very much.

First, let's start with a fine case.

Let's assume that I have this standard ElasticSearch URL : http://192.168.75.197:9200

With ElasticSearch documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_changing_the_client_8217_s_initialization_code.html

I can request it with this Java code :

```java
package com.acme.elasticsearch;

import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;

public class TestRedirect {
    private static final String rawURL = "http://192.168.75.197:9200";
    private static final String index = "demoindex02";
    private static final String id = "Zw6AXnEB8ovVkXyeZ9wF";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // parse URL
        System.out.println("URL = " + rawURL);
        URL parsedHttpUrl = new URL(rawURL);
        String protocol = parsedHttpUrl.getProtocol();
        String host = parsedHttpUrl.getHost();
        int port = parsedHttpUrl.getPort();
        String path = parsedHttpUrl.getPath();
        System.out.println("protocol = " + protocol);
        System.out.println("host = " + host);
        System.out.println("port = " + port);
        System.out.println("path = " + path);
        // instantiate HTTP credentials
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(Credential.user, Credential.password));
        // instantiate REST high level client
        RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, protocol));
        restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
            @Override
            public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
            }
        });
        RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
        // simple get request
        GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(index, id);
        GetResponse getResponse = restHighLevelClient.get(getRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        System.out.println("getResponse = " + getResponse);
    }

}
```

I can see in my console a fine result :

```
URL = http://192.168.75.197:9200
protocol = http
host = 192.168.75.197
port = 9200
path = 
getResponse = {"_index":"demoindex02","_type":"_doc","_id":"Zw6AXnEB8ovVkXyeZ9wF","_version":1,"_seq_no":16,"_primary_term":1,"found":true,"_source":{"id":"1","firstName":"Jason","lastName":"GIBBS","title":"Mister","company":"Mister","phones":["(413)442-5250","(413)442-5252","(413)454-5663"]}}
```

Now comes the issue : the ElasticSearch URL is redirected (for example, in front of Apache, Nginx or F5 ...)

The URL becomes : http://192.168.75.197:8060/v1/es/

This new URL is valid :

[image: URL check is fine]

**1. change only URL**

I adapt my java code with just new URL (client and request remain the same) :

```java
private static final String rawURL = "http://192.168.75.197:8060/v1/es/";
RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, protocol));
GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(index, id);
```

The issue is : 404 Not Found

```
Exception in thread "main" ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
ElasticsearchStatusException[Unable to parse response body]; nested: ResponseException[method [GET], host [http://192.168.75.197:8060], URI [/demoindex02/_doc/Zw6AXnEB8ovVkXyeZ9wF], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
];
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:1686)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1443)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1403)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1373)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.get(RestHighLevelClient.java:699)
    at com.acme.elasticsearch.TestRedirect.main(TestRedirect.java:52)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/html
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1703)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:1683)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [http://192.168.75.197:8060], URI [/demoindex02/_doc/Zw6AXnEB8ovVkXyeZ9wF], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>

    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:260)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:238)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1433)
    ... 4 more
```

**2. change URL & client only**

I adapt my java code with just new URL and add path to client (request remains the same) :

```java
private static final String rawURL = "http://192.168.75.197:8060/v1/es/";
RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host + path, port, protocol));
GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(index, id);
```

The issue is : Unknown host 192.168.75.197/v1/es/

```
URL = http://192.168.75.197:8060/v1/es/
protocol = http
host = 192.168.75.197
port = 8060
path = /v1/es/
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 192.168.75.197/v1/es/
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:809)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:225)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1433)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1403)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1373)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.get(RestHighLevelClient.java:699)
    at com.acme.elasticsearch.TestRedirect.main(TestRedirect.java:52)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 192.168.75.197/v1/es/
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:664)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalAddressResolver.resolveRemoteAddress(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:635)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.processPendingRequest(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:474)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.lease(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.requestConnection(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:377)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.start(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:221)
    ... 6 more
```

**3. change URL, client and request**

I adapt my java code with just new URL, add path to both client & request :

```html
private static final String rawURL = "http://192.168.75.197:8060/v1/es/";
RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host + path, port, protocol));
GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(path + index, id);
```

The issue is the exact same as in point #2 above : Unknown host 192.168.75.197/v1/es/

**4. change URL & request only**

I adapt my java code with just new URL and add path to request (client remains the same) :

```html
private static final String rawURL = "http://192.168.75.197:8060/v1/es/";
RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, protocol));
GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(path + index, id);
```

The issue is the exact same as in point #1 above : 404 Not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, answer is here : [RestHighLevelClient - Accessing an elastic http endpoint behind reverse proxy](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/resthighlevelclient-accessing-an-elastic-http-endpoint-behind-reverse-proxy/117306/2)

So I modified my code this way :

```java
        // instantiate REST high level client
        RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, protocol));
        restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
            @Override
            public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
            }
        });
        restClientBuilder.setPathPrefix(path);
        RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
```